# Javascript convert prototype based library to object oriented class

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have some old javascript library, which is written in prototype structure. 
I want to convert it into latest Class base structure.

I have search on google but cant find any available tool for it.
Or is there any other technique to convert prototype to Class.

Prototype sructure Example:

```
function Animal (name, energy) {
  let animal = Object.create(Animal.prototype)
  animal.name = name
  animal.energy = energy

  return animal
}

Animal.prototype.eat = function (amount) {
  console.log(`${this.name} is eating.`)
  this.energy += amount
}

Animal.prototype.sleep = function (length) {
  console.log(`${this.name} is sleeping.`)
  this.energy += length
}
```

I want to convert it into

```
class Animal {
  constructor(name, energy) {
    this.name = name
    this.energy = energy
  }
  eat(amount) {
    console.log(`${this.name} is eating.`)
    this.energy += amount
  }
  sleep(length) {
    console.log(`${this.name} is sleeping.`)
    this.energy += length
  }

}
```

I would like to keep comments as it is in the file. and there are some variables also which needs to be converted.

Comment: what is the problem

Comment: Client requirement and for easy of understanding as current library is too big and complex.

Comment: you would need to rewrite them manually. Even if there are tools available it's not recommended to use as there will be problems for complex implementation and logic.

Comment: Which tool is available? I would like to try once

Answer (score 2):

Try [Lebab](https://lebabjs.com/) the revers of [Babel](https://babeljs.io/)  great framework Transforms JavaScript

The transform of your code looks like this:

```js
function Animal (name, energy) {
  let animal = Object.create(Animal.prototype)
  animal.name = name
  animal.energy = energy

  return animal
}

Animal.prototype.eat = function (amount) {
  console.log(`${this.name} is eating.`)
  this.energy += amount
}

Animal.prototype.sleep = function (length) {
  console.log(`${this.name} is sleeping.`)
  this.energy += length
}
```

Note: some Transforms are **unsafe**

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30564840)